# Android AlarmManager - Cancel from another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, alarmmanager

I have a Homework Planner application which I want to create an Alarm for to remind users of the homework the night before/at a certain time. I have an Activity called AddNewHomework which is where the user creates a new homework item and it is added to the database. This code is then called.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AlarmNotificationReceiver.class);
i.putExtra("title", title);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), (int) id, i, 0);
AlarmManager mAlarm = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mAlarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 1000, pi);
```

This creates a new Alarm which is triggered in 10 seconds and creates a notification.

My problem is that I have another activity called HomeworkList which contains a ListView and displays all of the homeworks stored in the database. If a user long clicks on one then they have the option to delete it, however removing it from the database will not remove the alarm.

I have looked for code I can use to remove the alarm however I have not found anything that allows me to understand how to cancel the alarm from this different activity. I know that I need to make the PendingIntent's the same, but how do I do this as I cannot access the context from the other class. (I don't think).

Comment: you have try `mAlarm.cancel(PendingIntent);` for cancelling alarmmanager?

Comment: @imrankhan I have, however I need an identical PendingIntent for it to find the alarm and cancel it. My problem is creating the identical PendingIntent's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps, you could access your context from another activity, by making a static getter for the current context. In your above class, just make a private field:

```
private static Context context;

public static Context getAppContext(){
    return MyActivity.context;
}
```

Then, simply add in the onCreate method a:

```
MyActivity.context = getApplicationContext();
```

Accessing the context from another activity is now pretty easy. You can use the context retrieved from "MyActivity" to cancel your alarm.

Comment: can you explain a little more. I did like your suggestion to access the context in an adapter class , but i didn't success. can you plz help.

Comment: can you explain more detail, where can I put that code in both of my activity (activity to activate alarm and activity to cancel alarm) ?

Comment: @RaulRene Does it make a difference if you access it from another context? see http://stackoverflow.com/q/23038116/398348

Comment: All Activities should have the same Context returned from getApplicationContext(), I don't think caching in a static variable is necessary at all.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext()

Comment: @Paul Rene is the static getter and "MyActivity.context = ..." added to the HomeworkList Activity?  If there is a delete() in the HomeworkList Activity, then just add MyActivity.cancel() to it and then in the AddNewHomework Activity have MyActivity.cancel() that will cancel the PendingIntent and the AlarmManager?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Android: Does context affect filterEquals(), used to cancel alarm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787006/android-does-context-affect-filterequals-used-to-cancel-alarm) it doesn't matter if you use different contexts, this doesn't affect the recognition of the PendingIntent as matching. I have confirmed this in my own app, I set an alarm from one activity using the activity as the context, and cancelled it from a different activity using that activity's context, and it was successfully cancelled (the action wasn't triggered).

Comment: can you share your code for the activity as the context and then cancelling it from a different activity using that activity's context?

Comment: The code is here https://bitbucket.org/fk33/library-reminder-old/src/master/Library%20Reminder/src/main/java/uk/co/fk33/libraryreminder/SyncManager.java. You can see that there is a method called setNextSyncTime which takes a context as an argument, and another method called cancel which also takes a context. It doesn't matter if a different context is passed to cancel() than was passed to setNextSyncTime(), as long as the ALARM_ID is the same.

Comment: Ok, do you have an example of another class that calls the cancel()?  Would it be as simple as set up a SyncManager object in the other class as "syncManager" and then call "syncManager.cancel(Context context)"?

Comment: Yes, that would definitely work. In the code I linked, you call SyncManager.getInstance() to get the object. But the syncmanager could easily be a very normal, simple object with only set() and cancel() methods. You could create an instance of such an object in one activity, passing the activity as context, to set an alarm, then create another instance in another activity, passing the second activity as context, and cancel the alarm, if the alarm id was the same.