# Android: Does context affect filterEquals(), used to cancel alarm?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

To cancel an alarm, I use `alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);` which, according to android developers `Removes any alarms with a matching Intent. Any alarm, of any type, whose Intent matches this one (as defined by filterEquals(Intent)), will be canceled.`

If it compares 2 pendingIntents which are constructed with a different context and the intents they use have a different context as well, but the classes they refer to are the same, does filterEquals(Intent) return true?

So, pendingIntent1 has: context1 and an intent with context1 and class1.class

And pendingIntent2 has: context2 and an intent with context2 and class1.class

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they should be the same. According to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html#ComponentName%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29), the context is only needed to retrieve the package name of your application.