# Are there unintended consequences by registering or canceling the same alarm using different Contexts?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this method to register/cancel alarms that I call from two different Activities - hence the context passed in is different each time.

I designed it so that the alertId in the Uri is the unique identifier for an alarm - all other parameters class, category are the same.

However, sometimes ActivityA might register an alarm with alertId = 1 by using its contextA in the pending intent. ActivityB might update the alarm with alertId = 1 by registering it again by using its contextB. Similarly with canceling the alarm.

Will the same alarm get updated?

Hence, I was wondering if there might be a side effect to having different contexts while registering an alarm with the same alertId. Does anyone have insight into this?

```
static void registerAlarm(Context context, Alert alert, Date alarmTime) {
    // Get the AlarmManager Service
    AlarmManager mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent mNotificationReceiverIntent;
    PendingIntent mNotificationReceiverPendingIntent;
    // Create PendingIntent to start the AlarmNotificationReceiver
    mNotificationReceiverIntent = new Intent(context, NotifyActivity.class);
    mNotificationReceiverIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    // workaround from mazur - android bug database
    Bundle hackbundle = new Bundle();
    hackbundle.putParcelable(Alert.ALERT, alert);
    mNotificationReceiverIntent.putExtra(Alert.ALERT, hackbundle);
    mNotificationReceiverPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            mNotificationReceiverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mNotificationReceiverIntent.setData(AlertsDbHelper.getUriForAlert(alert.alertId));
    mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime.getTime() + JITTER,
            mNotificationReceiverPendingIntent);
    Log.i(TAG, "registerAlarm() Alarm Set for alert id:" + alert.alertId + " alarm Time "
            + alarmTime);

    Toast.makeText(context,
            "Alarm Set for alert id:" + alert.alertId + " alarm Time " + alarmTime,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [Android: Does context affect filterEquals(), used to cancel alarm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787006/android-does-context-affect-filterequals-used-to-cancel-alarm) it doesn't matter if you use different contexts, this doesn't affect the recognition of the PendingIntents as matching. I have confirmed this in my own app, I set an alarm from one activity using the activity as the context, and cancelled it from a different activity using that activity's context, and it was successfully cancelled, meaning the different context had no affect on identifying the correct alarm.

Comment: will take your word for it - have not tested it