# Android:AlarmManager and PendingIntent doesn't cancel from another activity

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I want to cancel and recreate the alarm in another activity. I have tried all possible things but its not cancelling.

I started my reminder like this(In Reminder Activity):

```
        Intent alarmintent = new Intent(Reminder.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmintent.putExtra("Subject", "a");
        alarmintent.putExtra("Comments", "a");
        int _receiverId = 0;
        try {
            Date dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm").parse(time);
             _receiverId = (int) dt.getTime();
            Log.i("current time millis", String.valueOf(_receiverId));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, _receiverId,
                alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        reminderAlarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        reminderAlarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
```

And try to cancel and recreate in other activity like this:

```
   Date date;
     try {
     date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss").parse(editedTime);
     _createId = (int) date.getTime();
     Log.i("current time millis receiver", String.valueOf(_createId));
         } catch (ParseException e1) {
           e1.printStackTrace();
          Log.e("Errors", e1.toString());
        }

    Intent alarmintent = new Intent(Reminder.getReminderContext(),  AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmintent.putExtra("Subject", "a");
    alarmintent.putExtra("Comments", "a");
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Reminder.getReminderContext(), _createId, alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);                                           
    AlarmManager reminderAlarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    reminderAlarm.cancel(pIntent);
```

I am sure that both pendingintent IDs are same and i am cancelling the alarm inside a thread.

The Reminder class Context I have used to cancel alarm has been created by [THE HELP OF THIS ANSWER(#Raul Rene)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055462/android-alarmmanager-cancel-from-another-activity)

All help and suggestions are appreciable.

Comment: Try using the application context `getApplicationContext()` when you create the `alarmintent` in both places (when you schedule the alarm and again when you cancel it)

Comment: thanks for reply. I checked it, but no change. Actually i am cancelling the alarm inside an adapter class.so m using its context before write anything.like context.getApplicationContext() ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many experiment I am able to cancel the particular AlarmManager with creating the same PendingIntent inside an adapter class.

What I did: I got the activity context through [the answer of Raul Rene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055462/android-alarmmanager-cancel-from-another-activity) . And for the PendingIntent id I have converted the alarm time into milliseconds and save this through `SharedPreferences`. I think this is a good way to remind Ids for multiple alarms or pendingintents.

And at last I have successed to creat the pendingintent in receiver class like :

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
Reminder.getReminderContext(),
receiverId,alarmintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And in Reminder class I also created the method and PendingIntent like:

```
//for the current context which is going to use in adapter or other class
private static Context mContext

public static Context getReminderContext() {
    return Reminder.mContext;
}


//Reminder Activity PendingIntent  
pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Reminder.mContext, _receiverId,
    alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Thanks to [David Wasser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/769265/david-wasser) for giving me a great suggestion.
Its working fine now.

Comment: I have a similar use case, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61161676/android-cancel-alarm-and-pendingintent-in-different-activity.  When I try to set up the private static Context mContext, Android Studio gives a warning "do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak."  Any ideas on how to fix?